# WorkManager + Hilt FAILED

Tags: android, android-workmanager, dagger-hilt

I'm following the documentation, but the WorkManager crashes even before the doWork method

manifest

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
        tools:node="remove" />
```

application

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MonitoringApp : Application(), Configuration.Provider {
@Inject
lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration(): Configuration {
    return Configuration.Builder()
        .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
        .build()
}
```

}

worker

```
@HiltWorker
class UploaderWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
@Assisted appContext: Context,
@Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters,
private val repository: Repository
) :
CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {
override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
    Log.d("UploadWorkManager", "Start CoroutineWorker")
    return  Result.success()
}
```

}

repository

```
@Singleton
class Repository @Inject constructor(
@ApplicationContext private val appContext: Context,
private val db: AppDb
```

)

start

```
val currentWorks = WorkManager.getInstance(context)
        .getWorkInfosByTag(WORK_TAG).get()
    if (currentWorks.isNotEmpty()) {
        currentWorks.forEach {currentWork ->
            Log.d(WORK_TAG, "CurrentWork ${currentWork.id}   ${currentWork.state}")
        }
        WorkManager.getInstance(context).cancelAllWorkByTag(WORK_TAG)
    }

    val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .build()
    val work = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<UploaderWorker>()
        .setConstraints(constraints)
        .addTag(WORK_TAG)
        .setInitialDelay(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build()

    WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(work)
    Log.d(WORK_TAG, "Start ${work.id}")
```

I started work< but when I show status, work FAILED

```
CurrentWork 6efa6352-be05-4bb7-9c0f-4be5a002b8c3   FAILED
```

====Update=====
The following error is displayed in the Logcat

021-06-11 21:37:10.698 15039-19464/XXXX E/WM-WorkerFactory: Could not instantiate XXXX.framework.workmanger.UploaderWorker java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:XXXX.framework.workmanger.UploaderWorker. [class android.content.Context, class androidx.work.WorkerParameters] at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332) at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2170) at androidx.work.WorkerFactory.createWorkerWithDefaultFallback(WorkerFactory.java:95) at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:244) at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:136) at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 2021-06-11 21:37:10.699 15039-19464/XXXX E/WM-WorkerWrapper: Could not create Worker XXXX.framework.workmanger.UploaderWorker

Answer (score 0):

Problem in provider

```
        <provider
        android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
        tools:node="remove">
    </provider>
```